# Using Windows, how can I have two applications in PIP mode?

Tags: windows-7, display-settings

For a kind of digital signage environment, I have two applications I want to be visible at the same time : one in full screen and the other windowed.
This *picture-in-picture* mode (aka **PIP**) mode being obviously better explained by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture-in-picture).

I want to be able to switch their display mode easily (typically, by pressing space bar, or using a button on the title bar of the windowed application).

Is there an easy way (typically an application/display driver) allowing that ?

Comment: can you define pip mode, it's not really a computer term e.g. here's a usage "Screen capture of SmartCam3D in picture in picture (PIP) mode. This helps sensor operators maintain a broader situation awareness than a telescopic camera "soda-straw". It was shown to essentially double the speed at which points can be located on the ground."     Not clear to an average computer person  so can you describe  a)it - that term , and, b)what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called **[OnTopReplica](https://ontopreplica.codeplex.com/)**. You'll need [.NET 4.0/4.5 framework](http://filehippo.com/download_dotnet_framework_4/) installed and it works on Windows Vista and later versions.

I'll let this GIF do the talking (click to watch) 
(VLC Media Player running full-screen and Windows Media Player running side-by-side)

[image: OnTopReplica side-by-side]